# Function to check for alphabetic characters

Tags: c

I created a Function to check if user typed a Real Name excluding all other non alphabetic characters.
Well, from my side, as a beginer in C language its works fine.
Anyway i have just a small problem, with the string name, if there is space inside that string i get wrong Name, but if there is only one name (michi) everything is ok.

```
        #include <stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

        /* Here is the Function which check if the string contains only: */
        /* abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz and ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ */
    int checkName(char *s){
        int i,length;
        length = (strlen(s));

        for (i=0;i<length;i++){
            if(s[i] == '0' || s[i] <= '9'){
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int main(){
        char name[]= "Michi";
        int check;

        if((check = checkName(name)) == 0){
            printf("\n\n\t\t\tYour name is:\t%s\n\n",name);
        }else{
            printf("\n\n\t\t\tWrong name:\t%s\n\n",name);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

My questions are:
1)
Did i found a right way of checking if string contains only non alphabetic characters.
2)
How can i extend my Function to skip spaces

Comment: If your name was "O'Brian" or "Smith-Barnes", I doubt one would say "Real Name excluding all other non alphabetic characters".

Comment: I changed the Title name.

Comment: the for loop that is looking for any characters 0...9 is not what you stated the code is to do.   The code needs a positive check.  I.E. for each char if ('a' <= str[i] && 'z' >= str[i]) || ('A' <= str[i] && 'Z' >= str[i])  then do nothing else error return

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `isalpha` in `ctype.h`. This returns `true` if a `char` is a letter, just like what you want.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/

By the way, if you're checking ASCII encodings, your function fails for characters such as '(' or '~'.

Comment: Well, it invalidates all characters under '9'. Are there any encodings where '(' and '~' come before '9'?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a valid set, test against this set, not other sets that might or might not be the complement set (So many sets in one sentence :-):

```
for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
   int valid = 1;

   valid &= s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z';
   valid &= s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z';
   valid &= s[i] == ' ';

   if (!valid) {
      return 0; // or any value you prefer to indicate "not valid"
   }
}
```

Comment: I have no clue what bool does but i get errors:
error: unknown type name ‘bool’|

Comment: I maneged to start learning C language at a begining of this Year and a like it.

Comment: add #include <stdbool.h> to your code for the boolean type 'bool' and the values 'true' and 'false'

Answer (score 4):

> Here is the Function which check if the string contains only:
>   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz and ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Looking at the code below that statement, you're lying. What your code does is checking whether there is a character `0` or any character below `9` in the string. Better do what you're saying:

```
if((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') ||
    (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') ||
    (str[i] == ' ')) {
  // fine ..
}
else {
  // not fine!
}
```

As you see I added the space to the set of allowed characters. To get rid of the if branch just negate the whole test expression (either by hand or using the `not` operator `!`).

The comparisons are working this way because of the layout of the ASCII table.

Note that there's a library function for this: [`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/)

Comment: I do know about that function, but i wanna try to learn C, i mean to write my own Functions. It helps me to learn faster, i hope.

Comment: I think that's a good way to learn. It's important that your code does what you say. Good and correct code can almost always be read like a sentence describing what it's doing.

Comment: Your code is not working, i mean this part i Allready try it :  "(s[i] == ' ')"...
I get "Wrong name"

Comment: @Michi `isalpha()` often returns true for more that `A-Z`, `a-z`, but also true for other `char` like `áíóú`, depending on your encoding set and locale.  Better to learn first how to properly use standard functions like `isalpha()` before trying to write them.

Comment: @Michi How exactly are you using the code? It's meant to go inside that for loop, and for a quick and dirty solution needs a `return 1` in the else block.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check only alphabetic chars and space, you can use `isapha` and `isspace` from `ctype.h`. These functions return non-zero for `ture` and zero for `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just continue the loop if the character is a space:

```
for (i=0;i<length;i++){
    if(s[i] == ' '){
        continue;
    }
    else if(s[i] == '0' || s[i] <= '9'){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you could also make sure it does not contain any other character than just alphabetic, by checking if all character are *not outside* the range of accepted characters:

```
for (i=0;i<length;i++){
    if((s[i] < 'A') || (s[i] > 'Z' && s[i] < 'a') || (s[i] > 'z')){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Note: the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) is a nice "tool" to confirm the range you have to check.

Comment: i didn't know about that "tool".

Comment: @Michi as you see in the ASCII table, the character '`A`' is equal to the number 65, so you can also write: `(s[i] < 65)` instead of `(s[i] < 'A')`.